# Postgres subqueries running extremely slow, Why?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I've found queries that are sometimes slow to respond and are looking at the execution (explain analyze) plan.

I think the joining part in the subquery is slow, but looking at the execution plan, I think the problem is that there are a lot of loops.

This is the query:

```
LOG:  execute <unnamed>:
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(messaging_channelmembership.id)
        FROM messaging_channelmembership 
           INNER JOIN messaging_member
              ON (messaging_channelmembership.member_id = messaging_member.id) 
           INNER JOIN messaging_user
              ON (messaging_member.user_id = messaging_user.id) 
        WHERE (messaging_channelmembership.channel_id = messaging_message.channel_id
           AND messaging_channelmembership.last_read_message < messaging_message.id
           AND messaging_user.is_bot = false 
           AND messaging_user.username != 'puddlrbot'
           AND messaging_channelmembership.member_id != messaging_message.sender_id)
       ) as unread_count
FROM "messaging_message" 
WHERE ("messaging_message"."channel_id" = $1) 
   AND (messaging_message.id >= $2)
ORDER BY messaging_message.created
LIMIT 30;
```

Explain analyze

```
Limit  (cost=169.00..169.00 rows=1 width=101) (actual time=218.212..218.218 rows=30 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=169.00..169.00 rows=1 width=101) (actual time=218.211..218.213 rows=30 loops=1)
        Sort Key: messaging_message.created
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on messaging_message  (cost=105.15..168.99 rows=1 width=101) (actual time=0.898..217.929 rows=369 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((channel_id = 1) AND (id >= 235589605))
              Heap Blocks: exact=12
              ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=105.15..105.15 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.371..0.371 rows=0 loops=1)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on messaging_message_72eb6c85  (cost=0.00..32.53 rows=1596 width=0) (actual time=0.163..0.163 rows=2078 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (channel_id = 1)
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on messaging_message_pkey  (cost=0.00..72.37 rows=3707 width=0) (actual time=0.142..0.142 rows=3066 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (id >= 235589605)
              SubPlan 1
                ->  Aggregate  (cost=59.81..59.82 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.588..0.588 rows=1 loops=369)
                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.27..59.80 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.578 rows=87 loops=369)
                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..57.62 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.359 rows=87 loops=369)
                                  ->  Index Scan using messaging_channelmembership_72eb6c85 on messaging_channelmembership  (cost=0.42..32.27 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.051 rows=87 loops=369)
                                        Index Cond: (channel_id = messaging_message.channel_id)
                                        Filter: ((last_read_message < messaging_message.id) AND (member_id <> messaging_message.sender_id))
                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 3
                                  ->  Index Scan using messaging_member_pkey on messaging_member  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=32016)
                                        Index Cond: (id = messaging_channelmembership.member_id)
                            ->  Index Scan using messaging_user_pkey on messaging_user  (cost=0.42..0.72 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=32016)
                                  Index Cond: (id = messaging_member.user_id)
                                  Filter: ((NOT is_bot) AND ((username)::text <> 'puddlrbot'::text))
Planning time: 0.462 ms
Execution time: 218.258 ms
```

[explain visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly0rz.jpg)

Comment: Try to rewrite the subquery into an outer join, so that you can get something that performs better than a nested loop.

Comment: better convert correlated subquery into subquery if possible.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The subplan should only be running 30 times, not 369 times.  An optimization to do that was added in v9.6, which is the oldest still-supported version, so you really need to upgrade.

But you can force it to do it that way with a Common Table Expression:

```
with messaging_message as (
  select * FROM "messaging_message" 
  WHERE ("messaging_message"."channel_id" = $1) 
     AND (messaging_message.id >= $2)
  ORDER BY messaging_message.created
  LIMIT 30
)
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(messaging_channelmembership.id)
        FROM messaging_channelmembership 
           INNER JOIN messaging_member
              ON (messaging_channelmembership.member_id = messaging_member.id) 
           INNER JOIN messaging_user
              ON (messaging_member.user_id = messaging_user.id) 
        WHERE (messaging_channelmembership.channel_id = messaging_message.channel_id
           AND messaging_channelmembership.last_read_message < messaging_message.id
           AND messaging_user.is_bot = false 
           AND messaging_user.username != 'puddlrbot'
           AND messaging_channelmembership.member_id != messaging_message.sender_id)
       ) as unread_count
from messaging_message;
```

Answer (score -1):

If your query is running slow, Nested loop is likely to be your enemy. Whenever you see that in your plan, there is a good chance you want to get rid of it. One simple thing that always deserves trying is to make it use a hash join.

Other than in e.g. SQL server, in postgresql there doesn't seem to be a direct way in the query to force a hash join.

Here is a question that might help do that:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/181674/undesirable-nest-loop-vs-hash-join-in-postgresql-9-6

As a temporary (!) solution, you can disable the use of nested in the planner with `enable_nestloop(false)`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-query.html